# Auto activate profile defined in settings.xml from pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have some related project properties setted in a profile in settings.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>project_profile</id>
    <properties>
      <project.scm>/path/to/directory</project.scm>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

and in my pom.xml i want the project profile will be activtated by default with this

```
<profile>
    <id>project_profile</id>
     <activation>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
</profile>
```

but aren't activated, any know how i can archive this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have profile in settings.xml, you either should put properties you always use there and  make this profile active right in settings.xml (suppose that profile contains something very common to all your projects) OR you need to make profile in settings.xml innactive by default and activate them when you build your project with **mvn -P custom_profile clean install**.

As correctly mentioned by @Jaffar Ramay, you can't control activation of profiles defined in your settings.xml from your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Profile activation is based on *SYSTEM* properties.

you cannot activate profiles based on properties defined in your pom or by something else

you cannot activate profiles after the build plan has started execution

Comment: It doesn't seem to be based on System properties, rather on command line argument. Otherwise, it would be possible to provide these properties from the pom.xml...

Answer (score 0):

This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, no profiles other than those specified in the option argument will be activated.
Activate Profile:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P profile-1,profile-2
```

Now you can invoke profile-1 using the command:

```
mvn -Pprofile-1 install
```

Deactivating a profile

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2
```

Profiles can be activated in the Maven settings, via the  section. Profiles listed in the  tag would be activated by default every time a project use it.
Profiles can be automatically triggered based on the detected state of the build environment. These triggers are specified via an  section in the profile itself. But then you need to specify the profile that you want to trigger when you run a test.